# Add a prebuilt .so file to android project and load it using dlopen with ndk

Tags: android-ndk, makefile

I have a prebuilt shared object file (mylib.so) and API file (mylib.h) also. Now I have to include these files in my project. I want to call the functions in this library using native interface.

But the header file provided for library is not **JNI specific header file**, it is common C header file. I want to load this library using `dlopen` and getting symbols using `dlsym`. So i can call these functions using functions pointers returned by `dlsym`.

**What I am requesting**

--> **Android.mk** file

--> dlopen (**lib_path**, RTLD_LAZY); path to **mylib.so** after installing apk file

If anybody tried like this and succeeded, please help me.

Answer (score 0):

To start with your second question, it's often much easier to call Java `System.Load("my")` to get **libmy.so** into memory, instead of using `dlopen()`. In your JNI module, you can still use `dlsym()` if you need to, but normally it will automagically find the right exported functions if you provide **libmy.so** to the linker in your **Android.mk**.

Please read the related NDK document http://source-android.frandroid.com/ndk/docs/PREBUILTS.html: its explanations are really good.